# want to fetch the form records

Tags: javascript, html

I had made a form and entered the records and apply validations..I want that when user click submit button then the values of all fields should be displayed on same page...But I am not able to fetch the radio button field record....... Below is my  code......

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>REGISTRATION FORM</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="Bisque ">
<form name='myform' onsubmit="return formValidation()" >
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr align="right">
<td align="center"><b>REGISTRATION FORM</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="yellow">NAME</td>
<td bgcolor="orange"><input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter valid name" />
<p id="demo" class="class1"> </p>
</td>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="yellow">AGE</td>
<td bgcolor="orange"><input type="text" id="age"  />
<p id="demo1" class="class1"> </p>
</td>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="yellow">GENDER</td>
<td bgcolor="orange"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /> Male<br>
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> Female<br>
 <p id="demo2" class="class1"> </p>
 </td>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="yellow">COUNTRY</td>
 <td bgcolor="orange"><select id="country">
 <option  value="Default">(Please select a country)</option>
  <option value="india">INDIA</option>
  <option value="usa">USA</option>
  <option value="australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="canada">Canada</option>

</select>
 <p id="demo3" class="class1"> </p>
</td>




<tr>
<td bgcolor="yellow">LANGUAGES</td>
<td bgcolor="orange"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="English" checked />English<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="Hindi" />Hindi<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="French" />French<br>
   <p id="demo4" class="class1"> </p>
</td>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="yellow" >INTEREST</td>
<td bgcolor="orange"> <textarea name="message1" id="message" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>]
<p id="demo5" class="class1"> </p></td>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit"></td>
</table>
<div id="div1"></div>
</form>
<style>
p.class1{
color:red;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function formValidation()  
 {    
   var html="";
   var st=0;
   var uname = document.getElementById("name").value; 
   var uage = document.getElementById("age").value;    
   var ucountry = document.getElementById("country").value;   

    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/; 

    if( letters.test(uname) && (uname!=""))  
    {

     html +="Name- " + uname+"<br/>";
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="";
    }  
    else  
    {  
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=" ";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Please enter valid name";    

    }  

      var age1=/^[1-9]?[0-9]{1}$|^100$/;
      if(age1.test(uage) && (uage!=""))
         {
         html+="Age- "+ uage+"<br/>";
         document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML="";
          }
         else
          {
            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML="Please enter valid name";

           }

     if(ucountry == "Default" || (ucountry.value=""))  
        {  
          document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML="Please enter valid name"; 

        }  
          else  
           {  
                html+="Country- " + ucountry+"<br/>";
                document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML="";
           }  

      var group=document.getElementsByName("gender").length;
      for(var i=0;i<group.length;i++){
      if(group[i].checked)
      group=document.getElementById()
      break;

      }

       html+=group.value;
       alert(html);
      if (i==group.length)
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML="Please select your gender";

    /*var group1=document.myform.language;
      for(var i=0;i<group1.length;i++){
      if(group1[i].checked)
      break;
      }
      if (i==group1.length)
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML="Please select your gender";

        var textvalue=document.getElementById("message");

        if(textvalue.value =="")
            {
                               document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML="Please enter interest";
               html+=textvalue;
               }

                   if(st==1)
                   {
                   return false;
                   }
                    else
                    {
                    return true;
                    }*/

                    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=html;
    return false;               
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function () {
                if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
            return o;
        };

        form = $('#myform').serializeObject(); // myform is id of your form

        var data = JSON.stringify({ model: form });
        console.log(data);
```

Add above code in formValidation function. you will get form data with form control name as key in json. Base on JSON you can validate data.

Comment: need it in simple javascript

Comment: it's simple just try it. you will get all control data in json. you don't have to write separate code of different type control like checkbox, radio button all other. it's common code for get control value in JSON.